# Fatal error: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document in selenium with nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, selenium

I am facing this issue while running the UI regression test. I have used **Typescript** for automation in **Selenium** and I have around 80 test cases. So when executing all at once, it executes some of the test cases smoothly but after sometimes in one of the testcase this error comes up and stops the execution. I am using only one thread for running these tests.

```
"noOfThreads": "1",
```

There is no issue with the individual test cases as they work fine when running individually

Answer (score 0):

`StaleElementException` occurs when the the driver tries to perform an action on an element which was once present in the DOM but does not exist anymore. For example, if you store an element in a variable, perform some changes which introduces variation in the DOM structure and the original element is lost, and now your driver tries to access it, this would fail.

In your case, when you are running the tests individually, there is no effect of one scenario on the next one. This is why the tests pass. However, when you run all of them together, this can introduce a change in the DOM.

Try to debug the test which failed by running a few tests before it.

Comment: For finding the element I have used xpath(contructed xpath using contains) and also tried it with name as it doesn't has 'id' in it. So does DOM changes affects in finding the element if used any of these? And I have verified on the page itself, I can still find the element using xpath or name.

Comment: this error is also thrown when element is there, but something about it has changed in between the time the element was found and when you act on it... (usually position)

Comment: also consider that number of threads does not define whether functions are synchronous/asynchronous... most javascript calls (client and possibly on your side depending on the call) will be made asynchronous, where Selenium will be synchronous.... doesn't matter how many threads.

Comment: @pcalkins as you said the position might change or something would have changed in between finding the element and performing an action on it, so can you please tell me what could be the possible things which get changed. I have used the XPath like //*[contains(@href,'operation=modify_textboxValue')] which is unique on that page and doesn't get changed during the test execution.

Comment: I am not seeing the error now, not sure if it's a proper solution. The system browser was on Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) and I was using the "chromedriver": "^2.46.0" for running the test. So, I updated it ("chromedriver": "^76.0.1") and now it is working fine.

Comment: The XPath would remain the same.  This could happen if client side script is still updating the DOM in between finding the element and acting on it.  So it's a timing thing...  you can catch/detect the stale element exception and try again until it stops throwing the error or a certain count is reached. (A webdriverwait will poll every half second...)